# Somar valor dos array JSON em PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Olá. Estou precisando somar todos os arrays `totalValue` dessa estrutura Json.
Nesse caso eu queria que retornasse 18897+13709 = 32.606

```
array(5) {
  ["list"]=&gt;
  array(9) {
    **[0]**=&gt;
    array(29) {
      ["orderId"]=&gt;
      string(16) "10611855449-01"
      ["creationDate"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-22T00:30:54.0000000+00:00"
      ["clientName"]=&gt;
      string(12) "Guedes"
      ["items"]=&gt;
      NULL
      **["totalValue"]**=&gt;
      float(18897)
      ["paymentNames"]=&gt;
      string(4) "Visa"
      ["status"]=&gt;
      string(8) "invoiced"
      ["statusDescription"]=&gt;
      string(8) "Faturado"
      ["marketPlaceOrderId"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["sequence"]=&gt;
      string(6) "123456"
      ["salesChannel"]=&gt;
      string(1) "1"
      ["affiliateId"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["origin"]=&gt;
      string(11) "Marketplace"
      ["workflowInErrorState"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["workflowInRetry"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["lastMessageUnread"]=&gt;
      string(143) " --&gt; 96 pedido nº 1063611855449-01 Pedido Entregue! Entrega realizada em Entregue Olá, . Obrigado por escolher a nossa loja. Seu produto já "
      ["ShippingEstimatedDate"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["ShippingEstimatedDateMax"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-22T10:00:00.0000000+00:00"
      ["ShippingEstimatedDateMin"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-22T10:00:00.0000000+00:00"
      ["orderIsComplete"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["listId"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["listType"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["authorizedDate"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-22T00:31:08.0000000+00:00"
      ["callCenterOperatorName"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["totalItems"]=&gt;
      int(22)
      ["currencyCode"]=&gt;
      string(3) "BRL"
      ["hostname"]=&gt;
      string(13) "asdfghjkklg"
      ["invoiceOutput"]=&gt;
      array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        string(5) "56070"
      }
      ["invoiceInput"]=&gt;
      NULL
    }
    **[1]**=&gt;
    array(29) {
      ["orderId"]=&gt;
      string(16) "1063976954-01"
      ["creationDate"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-21T23:49:37.0000000+00:00"
      ["clientName"]=&gt;
      string(16) "Arimatsu"
      ["items"]=&gt;
      NULL
      **["totalValue"]**=&gt;
      float(13709)
      ["paymentNames"]=&gt;
      string(9) "Card"
      ["status"]=&gt;
      string(8) "invoiced"
      ["statusDescription"]=&gt;
      string(8) "Faturado"
      ["marketPlaceOrderId"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["sequence"]=&gt;
      string(6) "549845"
      ["salesChannel"]=&gt;
      string(1) "1"
      ["affiliateId"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["origin"]=&gt;
      string(11) "Marketplace"
      ["workflowInErrorState"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["workflowInRetry"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["lastMessageUnread"]=&gt;
      string(143) " --&gt; 96 pedido nº 1063602976954-01 Pedido Entregue! Entrega realizada em Entregue Olá, . Obrigado por escolher a nossa loja. Seu produto já "
      ["ShippingEstimatedDate"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["ShippingEstimatedDateMax"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-22T10:00:00.0000000+00:00"
      ["ShippingEstimatedDateMin"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-22T10:00:00.0000000+00:00"
      ["orderIsComplete"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["listId"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["listType"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["authorizedDate"]=&gt;
      string(33) "2020-09-22T11:20:17.0000000+00:00"
      ["callCenterOperatorName"]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["totalItems"]=&gt;
      int(14)
      ["currencyCode"]=&gt;
      string(3) "BRL"
      ["hostname"]=&gt;
      string(13) "efefqergwreg"
      ["invoiceOutput"]=&gt;
      array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        string(5) "56067"
      }
      ["invoiceInput"]=&gt;
      NULL
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Utilize **json_decode** para obter uma variável PHP contendo os valores. A partir daí, itere pela variável e faça a soma de todos os elementos:

```php
   $meu_array = json_decode($json);

    $soma = 0;
    foreach($meu_array as $elementoAtual){
        $soma += $elementoAtual['totalValue'];
    }
```

Isso funciona para um json com N elementos, mas se for apenas 2, você pode simplificar:

```php
   $soma = $meu_array[0]['totalValue'] + $meu_array[1]['totalValue']
```